# Is there any way to disabling caching for a single field for anonymous users?

Tags: 7, caching, commerce

I ran into an interesting, but probably a common, problem. With caching turned on, stock is not updated immediately for anonymous users (which makes sense as that's the point of caching). However this results in a little bit of a UXWTF. When a product is out of stock, users are still shown that '1' is still available. It's only when they try to add it to the cart, they are met with a notice

The maximum quantity of 'product name' that can be purchased is 0.

I would still like to keep cache pretty much for everything else, but is there a way to disable caching of the available stock count?

Comment: Can you pull the stock value into a block? If so you could display it as a block and use Ajax Blocks: http://drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks/

Comment: Unfortunately this approach would really only work with a single product display/single product entity (or even if there were two or three product variations). This approach can get unwieldily when there are more than a couple product variations for each product display.

Comment: AJAX and/or ESI/SSI is one answer http://drupal.org/project/esi. Cache invalidation is the other answer http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions. Both of these are semi complex and thus not a drop in solution.

Comment: I just came across this issue http://drupal.org/node/1785158 and the module author quotes "Commerce sites don't work well with caching and drupal commerce is no exception.".

Comment: Can't write worthy answer now, but take a look at [Drupal 7 - Update node fields via ajax/frontpage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5228370/2389310) - consider just updating that one field using AJAX and timer. That way even QTY changes after user opened page will get reflected.

Comment: Firstly, only currently low stock items are likely to be a problem. So you could exclude their pages from cache selectively. Also you could avoid displaying exact stock numbers and show a low stock indicator instead - perhaps "low stock - order now to avoid disappointment". And the message shown when out of stock needs to be made friendlier, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea - in this case a workaround might be to hook a function after an order has been placed and then clean the cache programmatically.

You can use the `hook_commerce_checkout_complete()` and there call the `cache_clear_all()` function.

Comment: won't cache_clear_all() be a big performance hit as it is clearing the whole site cache. Also if the site is a busy one it might just choke up.

Comment: True; I was thinking about the same and the solution would be to clean only cache from Commerce module. Not sure what exactly should be called or if there is a function for that.

Comment: @junedkazi [cache_clear_all](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7) is actually somewhat poorly named. It accepts a parameter, where you can specify individual pages/cached objects to clear.

Answer (score 0):

The caching mecanism in Drupal is very flexible. You could use a custom cache for the parts of a page you want to be "un-cached" on certain conditions, and when the condition is met (a checkout), just reset the cache for that particular $cid in the checkout's form submit.

See [this post](http://2bits.com/articles/examples-drupal-custom-caching-adding-cache-timestamp-cached-pages.html) for a good overview of the caching api.